# HTML Form & PHP Script - Not Submitting Data to MySQL DB Table

Tags: php, mysqli, forms, http-post

I've have a simple HTML contact form and a PHP script to submit the data to a MySQL DB.

Everything seems to be working fine - my browser is showing [the data was submitted](http://d.pr/i/4A0n) - except the data doesn't show up in the DB Table in phpMyAdmin. All I see is ["MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."](http://d.pr/i/13YDZ)

Here is the PHP Script:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("db.example.com","dbo","*********")  or die("failed to connect to server !!"); 
mysqli_select_db($link,"db");
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$errorMessage = "";
$PropertyAddress=$_POST['PropertyAddress'];
$City=$_POST['City'];
$State=$_POST['State'];
$ZipCode=$_POST['ZipCode'];
$AskingPrice=$_POST['AskingPrice'];
$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];


// Validation will be added here

if ($errorMessage != "" ) {
echo "<p class='message'>" .$errorMessage. "</p>" ;
}
else{

//Inserting record in table using INSERT query

$insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `db`.`House_Leads`
(`PropertyAddress`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode, `AskingPrice`, `Name`,
`Phone`, `Email`) VALUES ('$PropertyAddress, '$City', 
'$State', '$ZipCode', '$AskingPrice', '$Name', '$Phone', '$Email')";
mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
}
?>
```

Here is my HTML form:

```html
<form role="form" action="houseleads.php" method="POST" class="contact clearfix">
  <p class="text _text text-4">Property Information</p>
  <input class="_input _input-1" name="PropertyAddress" placeholder="Property Street Address" type="text">
  <div class="container container-2 clearfix">
    <input id="city" class="_input" name="City" placeholder="City" type="text">
    <input id="state" class="_input _input-3" name="State" placeholder="State" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="container container-3 clearfix">
    <input id="zipcode" class="_input" name="ZipCode" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text" maxlength="5">
    <input id="price" class="_input _input-5" name="AskingPrice" placeholder="Your Asking Price" type="number" step="5000">
  </div>
  <p class="text _text text-5">Contact Information</p>
  <div class="container container-4 clearfix">
    <input id="name" class="firstname" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text">
    <input id="phone" class="_input _input-6" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" type="tel" maxlength="10">
  </div>
  <input id="email" class="_input _input-7" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
  <button id="submit" class="_button" type="submit">Get an Offer</button>
</form>
```

Any help or insights would be appreciated. This is my first attempt at using PHP and after struggling with this for a few hours X-) I'm at a loss.

EDIT: Along with the missing backticks identified by Chris - I was missing  `name="submit"` in the form button's HTML.

Comment: Please lookup prepared statements. You don't want to insert directly from a $_POST. It will help immensely here.

Comment: echo the `$insqDbtb` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a single-quote and a back-tick in your SQL query. It should be:

```
$insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `db594303259`.`House_Leads`
(`PropertyAddress`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode`, `AskingPrice`, `Name`,
`Phone`, `Email`) VALUES ('$PropertyAddress', '$City', 
'$State', '$ZipCode', '$AskingPrice', '$Name', '$Phone', '$Email')";
```

(`ZipCode` was missing the back-tick and `$propertyAddress` the single-quote.)

The query will probably work if you correct this.

EDIT: Try this in phpMyAdmin.

```
INSERT INTO `db594303259`.`House_Leads`
(`PropertyAddress`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode`, `AskingPrice`, `Name`,
`Phone`, `Email`) VALUES ('test1', 'test2', 
'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test8')
```

Do you get any errors?

Also, you probably don't need to select the database again in your query. So you can just have:

```
INSERT INTO `House_Leads` ( ...
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this. I've updated the code, but still nothing in the DB. I'm going to look into prepared statements as suggested by @blahfunk

Comment: Can you also post your database structure? It might be failing because a column is not spelled right, or because the input is of wrong datatype. Also, did you check that all `$_POST` variables are being sent properly from the form to the handler file?

Comment: `dbo594303259` is username and `db594303259` is DB name

Comment: Oh, I see. Many times username and database name is the same, hence my comment.

Comment: I can't see any error right off the bat. Try entering the code I added above directly into the database (SQL tab in phpMyAdmin).

Comment: The copy/paste directly in to the DB worked and that got me thinking... I figured it out! In the form's HTML the submit button was missing `name="submit"`. Thanks for your help - I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help! When stuck, try placing out several `echo` statements in your code. When you then run it, you can see which ones are printed on the screen and which ones aren't. That way you can figure out where there is unreachable code. ;) - If my input helped you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.